# Set focus to dynamically added input text field

Tags: jquery, dynamic, focus

Please bear with me, I have searched for a solution but somehow can't find where I am doing wrong.

I have a simple table with one row and an input text field. I add an additional row whenever a value is entered into the text field (it will be done with a scanner). The scanner "types" the number scanned from the QR Code and then sends the tab key. So the field is losing focus and a new field is appended below. To be able to immediately scan the next item, I would like to focus on that newly generated field. But somehow it doesn't do that.

I have jQuery 3.3.1. What am I missing?

```
<table id="tablerep" class="table table-hover table-responsive{-sm}">
  <thead class="thead-inverse"><tr><th>BatchID</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trow">
      <td><input class="input-mini" id="i1" cnt="1" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#i1').focus();
  $('tbody').on('change', ':input', function() {
    vCnt = $(this).attr('cnt')*1 + 1;
    $('#tablerep > tbody:last-child').append('<tr class="trow"><td><input class="input-mini" id="i' + vCnt + '" cnt="' + vCnt + '" type="text"/></td></tr>');
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#i'+vCnt).focus();
    }, 10);
});
```

The new input field has the id `id="i2"`, but the set focus does not work.

EDIT: I tried the below pure Javascript code. It also does not put the focus on the newly created input field. However, when I put a debut stop in, and just hit resume, then it does work.

```
document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  if (hasClass(e.target, 'input-mini')) {
      vCnt = document.getElementById(e.target.id).attributes.cnt.value*1+1;
      $('#tablerep > tbody:last-child').append('<tr class="trow"><td><input class="input-mini" id="i' + vCnt + '" cnt="' + vCnt + '" type="text"/></td></tr>');
      setTimeout(function() {
         $('#i'+vCnt).focus();
      }, 100);
  }
}, false);

function hasClass(elem, className) {
   return elem.className.split(' ').indexOf(className) > -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly it seems that the problem was a missing element after the last input field. When I added a simple xx in an added footer, it suddenly worked.

My assumption is, that the tab sent from the scanner put the focus out of the document, so the focus was on the browser, not the document. When the tab jumped to the link, still inside the document, Javascript could put the focus back onto the input field.

I am still puzzled though, why the jQuery does not work.